# MySQL reinstallation

Tags: mysql

I want to reinstall MySQL Server. I cleared register before reinstallation, but when it is configuring it says

```
 error 1045 Access denied for 'root@localhost'(using password NO)
```

How I can reinstall it ?

Comment: It looks like just password issue.

Comment: On what operating system ? With what installation package ? What do you mean by "clear register" ?

Comment: Windows 7. Cleared register with CCleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the MySQL application will not replace / overwrite your existing databases so the old installation's databases (and root password) are still there. You need to do one of the following:

- If you don't need the data: Delete the MySQL data directory.
- If you want to keep the databases: reset the root password:
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html